# Route path is not working properly i tried to shows chats on the basis roomId but i can not work properly

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am trying to Render chats on the basis **Room ID** but when I try the URL it does not show my chat component on screen. I tried the `exact` path method which generally resolves this problem. Here is my router path code:

```
              import React from 'react'
              import './Messenger.css';
              import Messenger_Sidebar from '../Messenger_Components/Messenger_Sidebar';
              import Chat from '../Messenger_Components/Chat'
              import {BrowserRouter as  Router,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


              <Router>
              <Switch>
          <Messenger_Sidebar/>  
            <Route   path="/Messengger/t/:roomId" >
            <Chat/>
        </Route>
        </Switch>     
             
        </Router>   
       [I talking about this URL In general case by using Route path is    work fine but in my case it is not work for me][1]
```

Answer (score -1):

I did NOT get what you are asking for , but if you want to render chat component

```
<Route path="/Messengger/t/:roomId" children={<Chat />}/>
//or
<Route path="/Messengger/t/:roomId" component={Chat}/>
```

then use "useParams" hock to getting roomId

```
 let { roomId } = useParams();
```

i hope it works

Comment: Thanks for effort but i also tried this but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Now it work for me I remove switch from my code then i tried your code It work fine now